# How to convert decimal to hex in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a decimal number in the bash shell:

```
linux$ A=67
```

How do I print 67 as hexadecimal in bash?

Comment: the printf in bash is a builtin, it does not fork a shell.  I have changed my answer to give an example of it directly setting variables as in the question

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As a bash program:

```
#!/bin/bash 

decimal1=31

printf -v result1 "%x" "$decimal1"

decimal2=33

printf -v result2 "%x" "$decimal2"

echo  $result1 $decimal1
echo  $result2 $decimal2
```

Or directly from the bash shell:

```
el@defiant ~ $ printf '%x\n' 26
1a
el@defiant ~ $ echo $((0xAA))
170
el@defiant ~ $
```

Comment: +1 and acceptance for the information: `the printf in bash is a builtin, it does not fork a shell.`

Comment: `printf` is also part of `coreutils` - `printf '%x\n' $1` in a shell script does the job: `/path/to/script 26`